# Anyone have any ideas how to make Dark Souls work though PlayonLinux?

Tags: kubuntu, wine, 18.04, steam, playonlinux

Currently running Kubuntu 18.04, installed PlayonLinux and installed a version of Steam through it.  Seems to work fine with the Witcher games thus far but I tried playing Dark Souls Prepare to Die Edition and it won't connect online (not a big problem to me) and when I finished the character customization screen and it goes to load the cutscenes it goes to a black screen and stays there.  I think it has something to do with windows media player codecs not being present (and thus wine isn't able to play .wmv files), but it seems all the workarounds for the wine are outdated and don't function anymore.  I'm pretty sure the version still on my steam is the original Prepare to Die Edition as well, and unfortunately I can't afford to upgrade to the Remastered edition.

Comment: Could you fix it somehow?

Comment: Still not working if that's what you're asking about @kiltek